# Semantic UI transitions on page load

Tags: javascript, semantic-ui

I am using semantic ui. I want the transitions to occur when the page loads in browser. What I am able to do right now is hover on transition. Is it possible to do?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#animate').hover(function(){
        $(this).transition({
    debug     : true,
    animation : 'jiggle',
    duration  : 500,
    interval  : 200
  });
    }, function(){});

});

<h1 class="ui header" id="animate">
   <div class="content">
      Hello
      <div class="sub header">hello.</div>
   </div>
</h1>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add transition to the DOM element on the document ready function.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#animate').transition({
        debug     : true,
        animation : 'jiggle',
        duration  : 500,
        interval  : 200
    });
});
```

Here is the [FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/nighisha/f4afm9ht/1/)